# Django Socketio 101

Tags: django, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I try to implement a chat with django-socketio in my django app.

First, I have to learn about django-socketio, so I read the README of https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio

I really want to get the basis of it. So I try to create a simple thing where a message will be rendered through socketio.

My events.py:

```
    @events.on_connect
    def first_connect(request, socket, context):
          socket.broadcast_channel("my message")
```

My view:

```
   def chat(request):
     return render_to_response('chat.html', {} ,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My url:

```
      url(r'^chat/$', 'projet.views.chat'),
```

My html:

```
    <head> 
    {% load socketio_tags %}
    {% socketio %}
     <script>
       var socket = new.io.Socket();
       socket.connect();
       socket.on('connect', function(){

    socket.subscribe('my_channel');
   });

     </script>

     </head>
```

When I go to localhost:8000/chat, nothing appear.

So it's probably very basic, but how can I do to simply send a message through my socket and render it in my html when I connect to it?

I really want to learn about it, so if someone has a tutorial about django-sockieto, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Cody Soyland blog entries [here](http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/) and [here](http://codysoyland.com/2012/sep/4/django-gevent-djangocon-slides/). It may be outdated but I think you can get the feeling of what should be going on there. Also it's not about django-socketio.